Почему правка удалённого ответа поднимает вопрос в топ?
Я пишу длинный ответ. Сохраняю текст в удалённый ответ, чтобы никому не мешать. Но это не работает. Вопрос всплывает в топ после каждой правки. Это выглядит странно для участников, который не видят удалённые ответы: вопрос без причины всплывает, автор правки написан, а самой правки нет.
NB Я проверил в анонимной сессии браузера: вопрос наверху в "интересных", автор правки я, правка внутри вопроса не видна.
Почему так?
Можно ли сделать чтобы правки удалённых ответов не тащили вопрос наверх?
Как правильно писать длинные ответы на SO?

Это выглядит странно для участников, который не видят удалённые ответы - это факт или домыслы? Но в целом таеое я бы предложил отнести на MSE, так как оно вероятно актуально для всех всех сайтов StackExchange. С другой стороны, я не понимаю, зачем испольщовать удалённые ответы для написания, я писал порой длинные ответы и трудностей особо не испытывал.

@aepot, это домысел. Я не могу отменить то что я вижу удалённые ответы и проверить сам. :). Но вопрос одинаково всплывает в топ для всех (или я тут ошибаюсь?), логично предположить что он всплывает в топ и для новых участников.

@aepot, меня напрягает что длинный ответ остаётся в топе, потому что я пишу его частями, правлю опечатки и прочую мелочь. Это выглядит даже некрасиво: "как удержать ваш ответ в топе неделю? Наделайте опечаток, исправляйте по одной в день."

Попробуйте без авторизации глянуть.

@aepot, он в топе "интересных" ответов без авторизации.

Тогда похоже, что это действительно баг и его стоит отнести на MSE.

Ну и пусть всплывает - не жалко, вроде.

Насколько я понимаю, поднятие вопроса при редактировании даже удалённого ответа сделано специально. Чтобы появление новой информации (или удаление старой) не прошло незамеченным для тех, кто имеет привилегии просмотра удалённых сообщений. Порядок (сортировка) вопросов в списке не различаются для участников с привилегией просмотра удалённых сообщений и без оной, так же как и при просмотре без учётной записи вовсе. Таким образом, я не вижу здесь какого-либо дефекта, поведение, скорее всего, задумано быть именно таким.
Одиночный черновик (неопубликованный вопрос или ответ в процессе написания) в пределах сайта вполне себе сохраняется для одной учётки. Но если нужно несколько одновременно, то это уже сайт не поддерживает. Для подготовки множественных ответов/вопросов, вероятно, правильнее пользоваться отдельными инструментами редактирования с поддержкой Markdown.

Если даже предпросмотр на сайте врёт, показывая не то, что будет видно после публикации, то отдельные Markdown-инструменты видимо будут врать ещё больше :(

@andreymal несоответствие отображения предпросмотра итоговому варианту - это явная бага, их фиксят, если они обнаруживаются. Или есть известные случаи, когда такое признано нормальным и помечено как [meta-tag:статус-так-задумано]?

«их фиксят» — вы прекрасно знаете что нет)

@andreymal ну, по возможности :) красных меток "это не баг", тем не менее, нет.

Обычно для таких целей используется вопрос-песочница на мете.
Пример: Песочница для черновиков сложных и длинных вопросов\ответов на Mathematics SE.
Такие песочницы есть на многих сайтах (Meta SE Formatting Sandbox, ...), особенно если в сообществе используются MathJax и другие нестандартные способы форматирования).
Возможно, такую песочницу стоит создать и в Stack Overflow на русском. Единственные побочный эффект - это то, что песочница будет постоянно в топе меты - но многие сообщества с этим легко живут. Однако, это уже тема для отдельного обсуждения.
